# Problem mixing image with shaders

Tags: texturing, materials

I'm trying to mix a material with a color ramp with an image texture and I can't find a way to make it work.

This is my node set up for the material. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: This is my current node set up for the material in question]

Comment: I can't exactly tell what you are trying to do. Are you trying to make the texture gradient? Or are you trying to apply the image over the gradient.

Comment: The gradient is being used as shading. I want the texture to darken and lighten with the rest of the model.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you don't want to apply the shader to the actual face of the texture, all you need to do is plug the alpha of the image texture into the mix shader socket. This should make the faintly discoloured box disappear, as it will only apply the ColorRamp to anything that isn't the face.

Shader setup:

[image: Node graph]

Result:

[image: Rendered image]

If this doesn't work, then check:

1. The face has an alpha of 1, and everything else has an alpha of 0.
2. The shaders on the "Mix Shader" node are in the correct order.